# Contact Updation not working on multiple contacts same Type "Other"

Tags: java, android

I am trying to update the contactlist but the problem is when multiple phone numbers are saved under the same category "other" it updates the last number to all of the other numbers under the same category this is the code I am using

```
protected void update(ContactPhoneNumber from, ArrayList ops, int rawContactId) {
        String selectPhone = Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='"  + 
            Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'" + " AND " + Phone.TYPE + "=? AND " + Phone.NUMBER + "=?";
        String[] phoneArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(rawContactId), String.valueOf(type), number }; 
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(selectPhone, phoneArgs)
            .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, newNumber)
            .build()); 
    }
```